# How create an standalone (without DLL file dependencies) C++Builder console application like a Delphi application?

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

When I create a Delphi console application, I can deploy the generated EXE file without worrying about external DLL files. But if I create  very simple [C++Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++Builder) (version 2007) console application (no [VCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Component_Library)) the EXE file requires the `CC3280MT.dll` file to run.

How can I avoid which my C++Builder console application requires the `CC3280MT.dll` file?

Even this simple code cause this dependence:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI: CC3280MT.DLL + BorlandMM.dll are the two files you need to redistribute when you have runtime packages turned on for C++Builder apps, and they comprise the shared memory management layer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build project package C++ Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775229/build-project-package-c-builder)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. In the *project* options, uncheck the *linker* option "Dynamic RTL".
2. In the *packages* options, uncheck "Link with runtime packages".

Comment: I have both unchecked yet CC3280MT.DLL is loaded

Answer (score 2):

Also you should uncheck:

**Project Options -> C++ Linker -> Link with the Delphi Runtime Library ...**

Comment: rs2007 doesn't exhibit such option