# Project settings for building release .exe that run on all machines

Tags: windows, c++builder, bpl, c++builder-xe2

I am prototyping a user interface using C++Builder XE2. I need this project to run on all Windows PCs, whether they have developer tools installed or not.

How can I get all the required libraries to be linked into the .exe that I distribute to users, so they can run the application? What settings in Project Options should be set?

Users now report me this error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a FAQ for example [How create an standalone (without DLL file dependencies) C++Builder console application like a Delphi application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787267/how-create-an-standalone-without-dll-dependencies-c-builder-console-app-like)

you must turn off two things. Use runtime packages and link with runtime libraries.