# Build project package C++ Builder

Tags: c++, package, c++builder, bpl

I have written a GUI forms application in C++ Builder and am wanting to be able to run the .exe on another computer.

I am getting some .bpl errors when trying to run the .exe on another computer.

How can I combine all the required files into a 'package' such that the .exe can be run on computers that do not have the required files?

I have done Project->Deployment and a list of files have appeared, including the .bpl file. However, what do I do from here?

thanks

Comment: It would help if you could post the _complete_ and _unedited_ error message. Or if it's not possible to copy-paste the text then at least a legible screenshot of the error dialog.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How create an standalone (without DLL file dependencies) C++Builder console application like a Delphi application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787267/how-create-an-standalone-without-dll-file-dependencies-cbuilder-console-appl)

Answer (score 2):

Your .exe has dependancies on external .bpl files that you have not distributed to the other machines.  If you want the .exe to be self-contained so you do not need to distribute those files, go in to the Project Options and disable both the "Use dynamic RTL" and "Build with runtime packages" options.