# C++ Builder - Project x.exe raised exception class ELUInvalidResLibrary with message 'Invalid resource

Tags: exception, internationalization, c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder 2009 project which I'm trying to internationalize using korzh localizer plugin.

When I run my application and try to Initialize the language menu, I get an Exception of:

```
Project abc.exe raised exception class ELUInvalidResLibrary with message 'Invalid resource file format "C:\path\to\exe\abc.exe"'.
```

I find the resource reference to the executable seems a bit goofy. Any ideas?

**Progress Update:**

I have another project which is translating properly. So I referneced it. I noticed I was missing the abc_klr.res file in the project, so I added it and it got me past that exception on the `LocalizerOnFly->Init()`, but I get a similar exception when trying to change the language. The difference is the executable is no longer referenced and instead I get a "" as the resource reference... Below is a screen shot:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was fixed in two steps:

1. Add the resource file to the project then rebuild.
2. Clean the project and deploy directory of any translation related
       files, then refresh the language files.

Things are groovy again.

Comment: For new projects, I found that you also have to modify some of the compiler settings, otherwise you may have issues with the bpl references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775229/build-project-package-c-builder